# What is wrong with my ChangeListener

Tags: java, swing, jslider, changelistener

I have some code for a changeListener below. Basically I need to set the value of my Voltage variable to the value which my JSlider is currently positioned at. So if my slider was at 5 then my variable Voltage would read 5. However this does not happen and I am unsure why. Whats  missing which would set the variable to have the current value that my JSlider is at?

```
public double getVoltageFromSlider() {

sliders.voltageSlider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() { 

 public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent event) {

                Voltage = (double) event.getSource();
                Voltage = sliders.voltageSlider.getValue();
            }
        });
        return Voltage;
    }
```

Comment: There is no JavaScript in your question.

Comment: Won't that first line in `stateChanged` cause an exception? `event.getSource()` should the the JSlider instance.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Every time the program asks for the voltage, another listener is added.  That seems like a bug in itself.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is adding a change listener to the slider, it's not actually retrieving the value. The value you are returning is the value assigned to the `Voltage` variable, which I assume is a field of your class.

Comment: What would I need / need to change in order for it to retrieve the value that is on the slider and assign that value to the variable Voltage instead of adding a simple change Listener then?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are mixing two ways to get the voltage: 'Pulling' the value from the slider, and 'pushing' the value into the `voltage` variable using a listener.

What your code does, as pointed out by Marcelo, is that it attaches a new `ChangeListener` to the slider each time it is called, but then immediately returns the value currently bound to the `voltage` variable, without waiting for the listener to actually *set* the value.

Instead, you should try one of the following:

1. *Either* attach a `ChangeListener` to the slider when the slider is created, and have the listener set the value of the `voltage` variable. In this case, the `getVoltageFromSlider` method is not needed.
2. *Or* use the getter (or just call `sliders.voltageSlider.getValue()`) to retrieve the value of the slider as needed. In this case, the listener is not necessary.

My suggestion, however, would be to stick with the listener, since this way the `voltage` variable is always up-to-date. And drop the line `Voltage = (double) event.getSource()`, as the source of the event is the JSlider itself, which would result in an exception.